Custom Parameter are read as "(not set)" in Explorer Google Analytics
My product is a web-based video game and use Firebase with Google Analytics for tracking purpose. I don't know which Analytics version it is, becuase the Property ID only contains number. AFAIK, GA4 will have G-XXXXXX and the older version Universal Analytics will have UA-XXXXXX.
I created a Custom Event with parameters for tracking purpose.
This is how I sent my Event to GA:
firebase.analytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
analytics = firebase.analytics();
.....
.....
.....


analytics.logEvent('start_game', {
          level_name: levelName, //string
        });

    //Event Name = start_game
    //Parameter Name = level_name (10 different values, such as: "Sky", "Water" , "Volcano")

When I check the result on the GA Reports->Engagement->Events, the parameter with various values are shown correctly. This mean the event+parameter are recorded correctly.

When I created a Custom Audience and use the parameter level_name contains Volcano, there are users detected:

But, when I use it as a Custom Dimension in GA Explorer, the value of level_name is only (not set).

My purpose is to create a report to know how each level_name perform on the players. So, i can rank which are the most used.
I have created Custom Definition for both scope for level_name: Custom Dimension as Event and Custom Dimension as Users

And both doesn't work. I have created those 1-2 days before I use it on the analysis.
Anyone know what went wrong here?

Try after 48/72h

ah yes, it works now if i use specific date (09/12). My next question is, does is only valid for data after (09/12) ? Is it possible to get older data, because I don't see it on my explorer. The data only available if I include (09/12) on the timerange

GA needs up to two days to process your data and make it fully available for explorations.
